# Spiral filling an existing matrix in their respective positions in descending order efficiently

Tags: java, array, matrix

**Question:**

- Sort the boundary elements in descending order using any standard sorting technique and rearrange them in the matrix.
- Calculate the sum of the boundary elements.
- Display the original matrix, rearranged matrix and sum of the boundary elements.

**Code:**

```
import java.util.*;
class SortBoundary
{
    int A[][], B[], m, n; 
    static int sum=0;

    void input() //Function for taking all the necessary inputs
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the size of the square matrix : ");
        m=sc.nextInt();
        if(m<4 || m>10)
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid Range");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
            A = new int[m][m];
            n = m*m;
            B = new int[n]; // 1-D Array to store Boundary Elements

            System.out.println("Enter the elements of the Matrix : ");
            for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
                {
                    System.out.print("Enter a value : ");
                    A[i][j]=sc.nextInt();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /* The below function is used to store Boundary elements 
     * from array A[][] to array B[] 
     */
    void convert()
    {
        int x=0;
        for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
            {
                if(i == 0 || j == 0 || i == m-1 || j == m-1) // Condition for boundary elements
                {
                    B[x] = A[i][j];
                    x++;
                    sum = sum + A[i][j]; // Finding sum of boundary elements
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void sortArray() //Function for sorting Boundary elements stored in array B[]
    {
        int c = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<n-1; i++)
        {
            for(int j=i+1; j<n; j++)
            {
                if(B[i]<B[j]) // for ascending use B[i]>B[j]
                {
                    c = B[i];
                    B[i] = B[j];
                    B[j] = c;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /* Function fillSpiral is filling the boundary of 2-D array in spiral
     * way from the elements of 1-D array
     */
    void fillSpiral()
    {
        int R1=0, R2=m-1, C1=0, C2=m-1, x=0;

        for(int i=C1;i<=C2;i++) // accessing the top row
        {
            A[R1][i]=B[x++];
        }
        for(int i =R1+1;i<=R2;i++) // accessing the right column
        {
            A[i][C2]=B[x++];
        }
        for(int i =C2-1;i>=C1;i--) // accessing the bottom row
        {
            A[R2][i]=B[x++];
        }
        for(int i =R2-1;i>=R1+1;i--) // accessing the left column
        {
            A[i][C1]=B[x++];
        }
    }

    void printArray() //Function for printing the array A[][]
    {
        for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
            {
                System.out.print(A[i][j]+"\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        SortBoundary ob = new SortBoundary();
        ob.input();
        System.out.println("*********************");
        System.out.println("The original matrix:");
        System.out.println("*********************");
        ob.printArray(); //Printing the original array
        ob.convert(); //Storing Boundary elements to a 1-D array
        ob.sortArray(); //Sorting the 1-D array (i.e. Boundary Elements)
        ob.fillSpiral(); //Storing the sorted Boundary elements back to original 2-D array

        System.out.println("*********************");
        System.out.println("The Rearranged matrix:");
        System.out.println("*********************");
        ob.printArray(); //Printing the rearranged array
        System.out.println("*********************");
        System.out.println("The sum of boundary elements is = "+sum); //Printing the sum of boundary elements
    }
}
```

**What I want to accomplish:**

*I want to fill the original array A with the sorted boundary elements B in a single loop at their respective positions in descending order.In my code I have used 4 different loops for accomplishing this task.Any suggestions or help to make my code better?*

Comment: [Cross-posted on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48626241/1014587)

Comment: Does your code currently work as expected? As in, does it do the job?

Comment: Yes.i want to improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have no idea what's your question but here is a short method that's placing a boarder to a matrix. You could use the `a` as index for the B array.

```
private static void placeBoarders(int[][] matrix, int n) {
    int a = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4 * (n-1); i++) {
        switch (i/(n - 1)) {
            case 0:
                matrix[i%(n-1)][0] = a;
                break;
            case 1:
                matrix[n-1][i%(n-1)] = a;
                break;
            case 2:
                matrix[(n - 1) - i%(n-1)][n-1] = a;
                break;
            case 3:
                matrix[0][(n-1) - i%(n-1)] = a;
                break;
            default:
                throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
        a++;
    }
}
```

The logic I've used here is that if I split the boarder to four equal chunks and I start from (top left -> bottom left -> bottom right -> top right -> top left) then I will have four pieces of size n-1. If you write it dawn on a paper then it will take like 5 mins to calculate the indexes.

For the opposite direction (top left -> top right -> bottom right -> bottom left -> top left) you should swap the matrix indexes just like this:

```
matrix[i%(n-1)][0] >> matrix[0][i%(n-1)]
matrix[n-1][i%(n-1)] >> matrix[i%(n-1)][n-1]
matrix[(n - 1) - i%(n-1)][n-1] >> matrix[n-1][(n - 1) - i%(n-1)]
matrix[0][(n-1) - i%(n-1)] >> matrix[(n-1) - i%(n-1)][0]
```

and even add some more clarity I will define some variables so the things get a bit clear for you:

```
private static void placeBoarders(int[][] matrix, int n) {
    for (int i = 0, size = (n - 1), a = 0, chunk, chunkIndex; i < 4 * size; i++) {
        chunk = i / size;
        chunkIndex = i % size;
        switch (chunk) {
            case 0:
                matrix[0][chunkIndex] = a;
                break;
            case 1:
                matrix[chunkIndex][size] = a;
                break;
            case 2:
                matrix[size][size - chunkIndex] = a;
                break;
            case 3:
                matrix[size - chunkIndex][0] = a;
                break;
            default:
                throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
        a++;
    }
}
```

Here instead of using matrix[X][Y] = a, you should use a as index for the sorted B array so it will be like matrix[X][Y] = B[a];

If you need to take the indexes of the the matrix starting from (0,0) in the direction ( top left -> top right -> bottom right -> bottom left -> top right) then you could use this code :

```
private static void fillSpiralMatrix(int[][] matrix, int n) {
    for (int step = 0, a = 0, size; step < n/2; step++) {
        size = (n - step * 2 - 1);
        for (int i = 0, chunk, chunkIndex, chunkOffset; i < 4 * size; i++) {
            chunk = i / size;
            chunkIndex = i % size;
            chunkOffset = n - step - 1;
            switch (chunk) {
                case 0:
                    matrix[step][chunkIndex + step] = a;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    matrix[chunkIndex + step][chunkOffset] = a;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    matrix[chunkOffset][chunkOffset - chunkIndex] = a;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    matrix[chunkOffset - chunkIndex][step] = a;
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
            }
            a++;
        }
        if (n % 2 == 1) {
            matrix[n/2][n/2] = n * n - 1;
        }
    }
}
```

In this case we do define

Comment: My array A has the original array and Array B has the boundary elements of which I have found out the sum and also sorted it .Now my task is to fill the elements of array B in array A spirally.Why spirally you might ask? This is because I have to show the original array elements with the boundary elements .

Comment: If I get it right you have to fill the whole matrix not only the boarders ? is that correct :?

Comment: yes.Only the borders should be in descending order.For example consider the border matrix has [25,23,15,9,0,-2....] then 25 should be at (0,0) coordinates and like that the other elements should be arranged in a spiral order.

Comment: I will edit my answer but still not sure if I got your point correctly :)

Comment: Sorry I meant circular filling of boundaries in descending order not spiral.

Comment: I've tested it with n of  1001 and it's working fine :) If you need further explanation please let me know. In your case instad of matrix[x][y] = a, you should use matrix[x][y] = B[a];

Comment: Ok let me try to define the task properly. 
We have a NxN matrix and we have it's values loaded int A[][] from the user input. Then we have B[] of size NxN that we use to sort the values in descending order. After that we have to user first 4 x (N - 1) elements from B to set the most outer chunks of A. So for a matrix of size 3*3 it means that we need the first 8 (4 x (3 - 1)) elements from B to use respectivly as : [(0, 0), (0, 1)], [(0, 2), (1, 2)], [(2, 2), (2, 1)], [(2, 0), (1, 0)]. The other elements from B are skipped and the inner values of A are left as they are?

Comment: Yes.You have totally understood what I was trying to tell.

Comment: Would you like to make any more edits or should I accept the answer now ?

Comment: I need to know if this is exactly what you need... If you think that the answer is complete then accept it and I won't do any more edits :)